# Get objectname from an array in php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

trying to make a loop that excludes the objects that i can find in my custom array.

the thing is that i cant get the function to find the "name" of the object. in this case I want to exclude date from my answer.

The json answer look like:

```
"BasicList": [
    {
      "letter": "B",
      "date": "2020-01-01 - 2020-12-31",
      "meters": 44
    },
```

my code like this:

```
<?php foreach($row as $rowen) {
    $dontshow = array( "date");

    if (in_array($rowen, $dontshow, TRUE)){
        
    }
    else{

      echo stringisempty($rowen);
      echo "</br>";
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $item)
```

`$item` will be the *value* of the array items (i.e. `B`, `2020-01-01 - 2020-12-31`, `44`).

```
foreach ($array as $index => $item)
```

`$item` will still be the *value*, `$index` will be the *index* of the array items (i.e. `letter`, `date`, `meters`).

Use that `$index` part in your `$dontshow` check:

```
foreach($row as $index => $rowen) {
    $dontshow = array( "date");

    if (in_array($index, $dontshow, TRUE)){
        
    }
    else{

      echo stringisempty($rowen);
      echo "</br>";
    }
}
```